# Why does implicit conversion in CASE expression return zero instead of blank now?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2017

A CASE expression in a SQL query has suddenly started returning zero instead of blank. Now, I understand why zero is being returned, but up until August 22, 2019 when I made a small change to this query in the VB.NET program that uses it, it had been returning blank. Why? What changed?

Specifically, the CASE expression returns a person's age based on a DOB (date of birth) field in a database table. If DOB is blank, I want it to return blank. If it's not blank, I want it to calculate the age using this nifty piece of code I found here on stackoverflow:

```
(0 + CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) - CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(DOB AS date), 112)) / 10000
```

This is the CASE expression:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN DOB <> '' THEN 
          (0 + CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) - CONVERT(CHAR(8), CAST(DOB AS date), 112)) / 10000 
     ELSE '' 
     END 
AS Age 
FROM TableName
```

I solved this problem by CASTing the result of the age calculation as varchar, so, that's not my question. My question is, why had this CASE expression been returning blank ('') until August 21, 2019, and it now returns zero?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it should have "always" returned a number, [per SQL Server's CASE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression." *There are **no** remarks of a related server flag or behavior change*; and such a change would be a *huge breaking change*.

Comment: As such, my hypothesis are: 1) the *original* code or output was different than believed/expected; 2) the changes in the client code either caused the difference, or enabled perception of the behavior which is presumed to be different.

Comment: That is: "..but up until August 22, 2019 *when I made a small change to this query* in the VB.NET program that uses it" seems to be worth exploring, along with how the result-set is handled in VB.

Comment: Show your VB.NET code too ... before AND after your "small" change

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I realize all the reasons it should have "always" returned a number, but I promise you that, prior to 8/22/2019, it returned an empty string. The change to the VB code was simply adding another field to the query. And how it's handled in the VB code is beside the point, but essentially, if the Age field is blank, meaning the record contains no DOB, then another field called Notes needs to be searched for the string value "Age = [int]" and the int value extracted and used instead. Your basic kluge. Anyway, the question isn't about VB, it's about SQL Server.